# How to find a specific file in a Laravel application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a PHP file located at `holiday/app/Console/Commands/myCommand.php` with:

```
namespace Holiday\Console\Commands; 

$bob = file_get_contents('Storage/data/BE.json');
```

and it works.

However in `holiday/app/Http/Controllers/holidayController.php` I have:

```
namespace Holiday\Http\Controllers; 

$bob = file_get_contents('Storage/data/BE.json');
```

but I get

```
file_get_contents(Holiday/Storage/data/BE.json): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use helpers to get correct path. Here, use [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path) helper. For instance:

```
file_get_contents(storage_path('data/BE.json'))
```

This will create correct path to the `laravel_project/storage/data/BE.json` file.